# Executing a command after two SSH connections

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I am trying to ssh into two consecutive servers, and then execute a command after successfully connecting to the second server.

I am currently able to ssh into the two servers back to back no problem:

```
ssh -t server1 ssh server2
```

I am prompted to enter my password for server1, and then I connect to server2 automatically using an authorized key.

After I'm in server2, I'd like to open a Jupyter notebook: `jupyter notebook`.

So to be verbose, if I were executing this myself line by line, I would want to replicate:

```
ssh server1
ssh server2
jupyter notebook
```

Here are a few things I've tried:

**Attempt 1**

```
ssh -t server1 ssh server2 -t jupyter notebook
ksh: jupyter:not found
Connection to server2 closed
Connection to server1 closed
```

So here I'm successfully in server2, but running my command fails. I think what I need to do is somehow load my .bashrc file so that my path to `jupyter` will be defined. But I haven't been able to successfuly do this either:

**Attempt 2**

```
ssh -t server1 ssh server2 -t source /filepath/.bashrc && jupyter notebook
ksh: .: syntax error at line 45: `(' unexpected
Connection to server2 closed.
Connection to server1 closed.
```

So now I don't think I am loading the .bashrc properly. Or perhaps I have arguments out of order, I'm not really sure.

Comment: Your attempt1 clearly says that on the remote you are running **ksh**, so loading .bashrc (attempt2) is definitely not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "simple matter of quoting", so that the commands are self-contained on the respective servers:

```
ssh -t ujump 'ssh server1 -t "source /filepath/.profile && jupyter notebook"'
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (A)
#             ..............................................................(B)
```

Command (A) is executed on server1
Command (B) is executed on ujump